# Are there statistics on Sickle Cell Traits based on country of origin?

Tags: epidemiology

And where was it originally from and how does it spread?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you tried to answer this question? A simple google search answers the first for me.

Comment: @kmm - By country and by province, I have not found any statistics. If you stumble over an article, please kindly post it here.

Comment: Can I say all the Chinese with SCT have recent African or South Asian ancestry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "where does it come from and how does it spread?", why not read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle-cell_disease)?  Short answers: (1) malarial regions of sub-Saharan Africa; (2) movement of people and genetic introgression.

Googling ['sickle cell "country of origin"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sickle+cell+%22country+of+origin) turns up, for example:

"Sickle cell disease in areas of immigration of high-risk populations: a low cost and reproducible method of screening in northern Italy" *Blood Transfus.* 2014 Jul; 12(3): 346–351. doi:  10.2450/2013.0188-13 PMCID: PMC4111816

```
Country    Selected     Enrolled/   Enrolled/
                        negative    Hb variant
-----------------------------------------------
Ghana      241 (51.4%)  112 (47.1%) 53 (57.6%)
Nigeria    152 (32.4%)  77 (32.4%)  29 (31.5%)
Guinea      15 (3.2%)   8 (3.4%)    4 (4.3%)
Cameroon    13 (2.8%)   10 (4.2%)   1 (1.1%)
Senegal     12 (2.6%)   8 (3.4%)    1 (1.1%)
Ivory Coast 10 (2.1%)   9 (3.8%)    1 (1.1%)
Other       26 (5.5%)   14 (5.7%)   3 (3.3%)
Total      469 (100%)   238 (100%)  92 (100%)
```

"The burden of sickle cell disease in Cape Town", *South African Medical Journal* 102(9), 2012 Wonham et al. http://www.samj.org.za/index.php/samj/article/view/5886/4421

[image: pie chart of country of origin]

Distribution of sickle cell disease patients by country of origin. Up to 93.1% (n=54) of the patients were originally from other countries in Africa, mainly from the Democratic Republic of Congo (62.1%, n=36).

Comment: Thanks. Since SCT is spread by inheritance, not by malaria or mosquito, I wonder if the spread of this trait is correlated with the improvement of transportation technology and the human migration that came after it.